# How to put a directory first on the classpath with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot

I am building my Spring Boot application using Maven, so I can start it with:

```
java -jar myjar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod
```

I want to have a directory first on the classpath that would allow me to place some files on the filesystem without having to unzip the jar to change them.

I have tried using `loader.path`, but it does not seem to work.

```
java -Dloader.path="config/*" -jar myjar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod
```

The `config` dir is a subdirectory of where the jar is located. I am trying to load a keystore file which is injected as a `Resource` in my application. There is such a file in the src/main/resources, but that only works in my IDE, not when packaged as a jar. So I want to put a file first on the classpath so that that one is found first on the classpath.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `loader.path` but only if the `Main-Class` is `PropertiesLauncher` (so it depends how you built the JAR file). Maybe you need to re-build the JAR with packaging=ZIP in the Boot plugin (e.g. [docs here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging-optional-params))? Can you not set the path to the keystore as a "file:" URL?

Comment: Using `file:` does fix it and I can use it as a workaround. However, using `<layout>ZIP</layout>` in the Maven plugin does not put it on the classpath and I would really like to get that working. I get `NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/PlatformTransactionManager` when I add the `loader.path`

Comment: That's because you are removing the default loader.path. You would need "loader.path=lib/,config/" to use both.

Comment: Actually  the other way round (given you are asking for "config/" to be first).

Comment: Ah! I thought `loader.path` was to put _additional_ things on the classpath.

Comment: Does Spring Boot provide some way to add items to the classpath as opposed to replacing it entirely as it does when setting `loader.path`?

Comment: No. But if the default is a directory, it's hardly difficult to add it back in, is it?

Comment: Faced similar issue. using `<layout>ZIP</layout>` in the Maven plugin fixed the issue. Thanks!